# $\mathbb D$-weighted flatness of functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

It is a matter of unwinding the definitions to see that for a flat (set valued) presheaf the W-weighted colimit functor

W ⊗ _

commutes with finite limits: this is basically because the W-weighted colimit is a colimit over the opposite of the category of elements of W, and since W is flat the latter is filtered. This is in turn equivalent to the request that the Yoneda extension $Yan(W)=Lan_YW$ commutes with finite limits.

This can be generalized to the case of a sound doctrine $\mathbb D$ (see [1]) to get that the following are equivalent for a weight W:

1. Yan(W) is $\mathbb D$-continuous
2. Elts(W)° is $\mathbb D$-filtered
3. W-weighted colimits commute with $\mathbb D$-limits

Let now $\mathbb D$ be a sound doctrine: it is natural to ask whether there are conditions analogous to $\mathbb D$-flatness that ensure that W-weighted colimits commute with U-weighted limits, i.e. that there is an isomorphism

$$W ⊗ \{U, F\} \cong \{U, W⊗F\}$$

for weights W, U and $F : I \times J \to K$ a functor.

This condition stronger than $\mathbb D$-flatness is such that $\mathbb D$-flatness correspond to weighted flatness with respect to conical weights with $\mathbb D$-domain.

> Is this condition non-trivial? What is an equivalent condition for weighted $\mathbb D$-flatness?

The only reference I can find for this condition is [2], where no such
criterion is stated, at least at a rapid glance.

---

[1]: *Adámek, Jiří; Borceux, Francis; Lack, Stephen; Rosický, Jiří*, [**A classification of accessible categories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00126-3), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 175, No.1-3, 7-30 (2002). [ZBL1010.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1010.18005).

[2]: *Lack, Stephen; Rosický, Jiří*, [**Homotopy locally presentable enriched categories**](http://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/31/25/31-25abs.html), Theory Appl. Categ. 31, 712-754 (2016). [ZBL1346.18025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1346.18025).

Comment: See [Dostal and Velebil](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3090) for more discussion.

Comment: I'll be happy to accept an answer where you point out the more relevant parts of this paper!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking for. The ABLR statement says that (1,2,3) are equivalent when $\mathbb{D}$ is a sound doctrine of conical weights. Are you asking for a generalization where $\mathbb{D}$ is allowed to contain non-conical weights $U$?

Comment: Yes (I still have to look at the paper you link)

Comment: The equivalence of (1) and (3) is the definition of soundness (I assume that (3) is meant to say "commute in $\mathsf{Set}$). (2) doesn't have a good enriched analog, and anyway I think it shouldn't be expected to hold when $\mathbb{D}$ contains non-conical weights, since it basically says that the distinction between conical and non-conical weights doesn't matter. Nevertheless there are interesting things to say, I'll write something about them.

Answer (score 2):

[Dostal and Velebil](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3090) discuss soundness in the enriched, weighted context. Their main result is

**Corollary 3.11.** For a locally small saturated class $\Psi$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $\Psi$ is sound.
2. $\Psi^+(T^\mathrm{op}) = \Psi\mathrm{-Alg}(T )$ holds for any $\Psi$-theory $T$.
3. For any small $D$, every weight $\varphi: D^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{V}$ is a $\Psi$-ﬂat colimit of a diagram in $\Psi(D)$.
4. For any small $D$, the closure of $\Psi(D)$ in $[D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{V} ]$ under $\Psi$-ﬂat colimits is all of $[D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{V} ]$.

Let's unpack that. Many of the basic definitions are from [Kelly and Schmitt](http://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/14/17/14-17abs.html), which in turn is based on [Albert and Kelly](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(88)90073-4). But beware that some notation may clash with Kelly and Schmitt.

- $\mathcal{V}$ is a [(Bénabou) cosmos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosmos#bnabous_definition) in which everything is enriched.

**The hypotheses:**

- $\Psi$ is a *class of weights*, which simply means that for every small $\mathcal{V}$-category $D$, we designate some $\Psi(D) \subseteq [D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{V}]$. We might use the term "weighted limit doctrine" synonymously with "class of weights". We think of $\Psi(D)$ as a "conical" class of weights with respect to which we want to take colimits of functors $D \to C$ (or limits of functors $D^\mathrm{op} \to C$). When $\mathcal{V} = \mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ is a doctrine in the sense of [ABLR](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00126-3), there is a corresponding class of weights $\Psi_\mathbb{D}$ where $\Psi_\mathbb{D}(D)$ consists just of the terminal presheaf if $D \in \mathbb{D}$ and is otherwise empty.

  - $\Psi$ is assumed to be *locally small*, i.e. $\Psi(D)$ is an essentially small subcategory of $[D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{V}]$ for every $D$.
  - $\Psi$ is assumed to be *saturated* (the term used in Kelly and Schmitt for what was called "closed" in Albert and Kelly), i.e. $\Psi(D)$ coincides with the free cocompletion $\Psi^\ast(D)$ of $D$ under colimits of functors $E \to D$ weighted by presheaves in $\Psi(E)$ (recall that $\Psi^\ast(D)$ can be given canonically as a full subcategory of $[D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{V}]$, so this makes sense). Recall that every class of weights has a saturation $\Psi^\ast$, where we simply replace $\Psi(D)$ by $\Psi^\ast(D)$. The $\Psi$-flat functors and $\Psi^\ast$-flat functors (see below) coincide, so in some sense saturation is a mild condition. But many convenient doctrines (such as finite limits) are not saturated; in order to apply this result we need to think about the saturation of the doctrine and work backwards. Note also that the saturation of a locally small doctrine need not be locally small (e.g. the saturation of the empty class is locally large when $\mathcal{V}$ is the category of suplattices), so there's a bit of synergy between these two conditions.

**The key definitions:**

- For $\Psi$ a class of weights, Dostal and Velebil define a functor $\varphi: C^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{V}$ to be *$\Psi$-flat* if $\varphi \otimes \{\psi, F\} \to \{\psi, \varphi \otimes F\}$ is an isomorphism for all $D$, all  $F: D^\mathrm{op} \otimes C \to \mathcal{V}$ and $\psi \in \Psi(D)$, just as you suggest; this recovers the usual definition of flatness when $\Psi$ is conical.

  - $\Psi^+(D)$ denotes the class of $\Psi$-flat weights.
  - A $\Psi$-theory $T$ is just a $\mathcal{V}$-category with $\Psi$-limits, and $\Psi\mathrm{-Alg}(T)$ is the category of functors $T \to \mathcal{V}$ preserving $\Psi$-limits (think of Lawvere theories or Gabriel-Ulmer duality).
- Let's say that $\varphi$ is *representably $\Psi$-flat* if the above condition holds for functors $F$ of the form $C(G,c)$ where $G: D \to C$ is a functor. Then Dostal and Velebil's definition of *soundness* says that $\Psi$ is sound if and only if every representably $\Psi$-flat functor is $\Psi$-flat. This recovers the usual definition when $\Psi$ is conical.

**Discussion:**
Condition (2) says that Gabriel-Ulmer duality holds for the doctrine $\Psi$. So it's a condition that only considers $\Psi$-cocomplete categories. So it's remarkable for it to be equivalent to the other properties. Condition (4) basically says that any colimit is an iterated $\Psi$-flat colimit of $\Psi$-colimits, and Condition (3) says that this can be done in one step.

More can be said for particular doctrines. For example, Dostal and Velebil investigate the doctrine of finite products.